# google sitemap "index": shall I add all the children too?

Tags: sitemap

I've done my website, and I've sent my sitemap index, which points to 7 "sub" sitemaps (= 7 children).

[image: google "main" sitemap]

Do I have to send all my 7 "sub" sitemaps (= 7 children) too or shall I wait for google to fetch them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, google does this automatically. Just provide the main sitemap index. Here's an example of a sitemap that points to other ones:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap/0.84">
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://www.o.fr/sitemap_oa.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-01-31T05:28:02+01:00</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
  <sitemap>
    <loc>http://www.o.fr/sitemap_op.xml</loc>
    <lastmod>2012-01-31T05:29:02+01:00</lastmod>
  </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```